# Socket IO (Flutter+NodeJS) client listen not working

Tags: node.js, flutter, server, socket.io, client

Implementing an alert system where an alert goes only to some users. The issue is the server seems to send the event through socket.io ,but only the client that emited gets the alarm

Flutter :

```
 void startSocket(){
    if(!socket.connected){
      socket.connect();
    }
    socket.on('updateres/${mainUser.username}', (data) =>
    {users.clear(),
      for(var elem in data){
        users.add(User.fromJson(elem))
      }});
    socket.on('alarma/${mainUser.username}',(data)=>{print("HELP HIM"),socket.ack(data)});
    socket.onConnectError((error) {
      print("Connection error: " + error.toString());
    });
  }
  Future<void> emitUpdate() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    String latitude = position.latitude.toString();
    String longitude = position.longitude.toString();
    mainUser.latitude=latitude;
    mainUser.longitude=longitude;
    socket.emit('update',{'username':mainUser.username,'latitude':mainUser.latitude,'longitude':mainUser.longitude,'state':mainUser.state});
  }`
```

NodeJS (typescript) :

```
`const response=await socket.emit(`alarma/${elem.member}`,{latitude:elem.coordinates.latitude,longitude:elem.coordinates.longitude});
```